# how to pipe to a sourced function in bashrc file?

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, bashrc

we all know how to pipe to shell scripts and installed programs like grep,awk ... but what about a sourced function in .bashrc or .zshrc ?

this is a test function :

```
function fff(){
    echo "$@"
}
```

and this is a test command :

```
$ echo "hello world" | fff
```

and it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function expects command line arguments, not data over the standard input stream (which it gets when you pipe to it).

What you could possibly do is to test whether the function was given any command line arguments, and if not, output the standard input stream instead:

```
fff () {
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
       echo "$@"
    else
       cat
    fi
}
```

Testing:

```
$ echo "hi there" | fff
hi there
```

An alternative solution would be to use a command substitution with you original function definition:

```
fff "$( echo "hi there" )"
```

This would set `$@` in the function to the single string `hi there`.  This would be a perfectly valid solution if the piped data is a single string or a short line of text.  For processing larger quantities of data, consider doing so in the usual line-by-line manner (possibly using `awk`) in place of the call to `cat` in the above function definition, and read the data off a pipe as in the test above.

Comment: ultimately the function needs to capture the piped  data as a variable for other purposes

Comment: @NeoMosaid See updated answer.

Comment: thanks , ``aa=$( cat )``  ; captured the stdin data, and it's just what I needed